Is there such a thing as "Algebraic Classical Field Theory" (ACFT)?
This is something that has bugging me for a while, and that's why I'm asking. I've read some stuff about AQFT lately and althought it picked up my interest I also wanted to read something about ACFT (or even some sort of algebraic classical mechanics, if that even exists) but I failed on finding anything that might ressemble such construction.
So that's basically my question: Is there such a thing as "Algebraic Classical Field Theory"? And if it does not exist, why is that? Is it useless, uninteresting, or is there some sort of better answer to it?

Something like this? https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.2148

That's what Poisson algebras are for!

possibly useful: On the relation between classical and quantum observables - A. Ashtekar

Usually AQFT is concerned with finding, algrebaically, representations of an algebra of operators, the observables. So the idea is to first find the algebra of observables on the phase space, and then via constructions like the Gelfand-Naimark-Segal (GNS) construction, build representations of this algebra.
Since you can describe also classical field theories with the aid of Hilbert spaces, and since there exists also an algebra of classical of observables, you can apply the above treatment to find algebraically the representations of classical field theories.
Notice that, even if the algebra could be the same in some cases, the representations will not be identical since the Hilbert spaces of the classical theory and the quantum theory are going to describe different things. The elements of the classical Hilbert space are not states/rays of a probabilistic quantum ensemble, those being just the postulates of QM, and not built in into the Hilbert space itself.
